# Change the content of gadget.html from my settings.html on windows 7 gadget

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, widget

How can I change the content of my gadget.html through clicking my settings.html

here's my sample code

settings.html

```
<button onClick = "changeThis()">Clickhere</button>
```

my.js

```
function changeThis(){
document.getElementById('showhere').innerHTML = "Content Change";   

}
```

gadget.html

```
<div id = "showhere">Nothings Change</div>
```

but things don't go according to plan, tsk. I don't know if it's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript cannot alter other files on the file system. It only runs on the specific page which is requested.

If you want to alter the files or contents of other files on the server, you'll need a server side language, like [php](/questions/tagged/php).

Comment: Yeah, that's what I think. I just thought that in windows gadget its different, because 2 files are linked(maybe).

Comment: `System.Gadget.settingsUI = "Settings.html"; ` by putting this on my javascript, I don't know if it links, but they say it just refer to the html page. But I think this is not really possible.